# Regional settings on deployment machine for datetime not performing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, deployment, globalization

I deployed the application on normal windows 7 machine as it is central machine for official use. this is internal use application. bu the datetime manipulation on the deployed machine not working properly. since everything if working properly on development machine. I thought it might be the Regional settings issue but as i settled up same settings on deployment machine same like development machine, still issue is same. issue is deployment machine unable to understand the which is MM and dd. suppose i am sending date like "11-jul-2013" then somehow it converting it to "11-07-2013" this is ok. but date 13 will not work for this case.

**Edited:** I added

```
   globalization:
   fileEncoding="utf-8"
   requestEncoding="utf-8"
   responseEncoding="utf-8"
   culture="en-US"
   uiCulture="en-US"
```

in the web.config. but still problem is same. what should be the issue? really I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like it could be an issue with your culture settings. Try debugging by checking what culture is currently set (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) right before you are using the date.

Comment: Is is possible, i could globally set the culture for the application and no need to check everywhere ? how to get my local machine's application culture and how to set to deployed version ?

Comment: Try setting the culture in the thread, for example: Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

Comment: Thanks for reply, but If I am setting it in Web.Config then it is applicable for globally to application. No need to handle thread.

Comment: Yes but I'm saying you could debug it this way. Set the culture explicity right before using your function and see if that works, that way you can figure out if that is the problem or not.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing is inherently a difficult operation for dates. From your question, it seems like you are parsing dates from some type of backend (database, server, file, etc). In the case of backend date parsing/formatting, you should **always** use standard formats. This means using TryParseExact/ToString with a pattern such as [RFC1123Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.rfc1123pattern.aspx) and invariant culture. In the case of parsing dates from a frontend (direct user input), the current culture settings should work fine.